# selected Start date and end date from datepicke based on that I need to insert dates between start date and end dateinto sqllite

Tags: android

Iam fresher in android I selected Start date and end date from datepicker based on that I need to insert dates between start date and end date into sqllite and then compare with current date and set reminder. Please let me know if you have solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To get date from Date picker use this**

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
int year = datePicker.getYear();
```

**Set the values to database**

```
public  void onDateSet(DatePicker view,int year,int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth){
            dateTime.set(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);

   int year = year;   // Here you can get day,month and year.
   int month = monthOfYear;
   int day = dayOfMonth;

ContentValues values = new ContentValues()

values.put("Day",dayOfMonth);
values.put("Month",monthOfYear);
values.put("Year",year);

}
```

You can get the database tutorials from [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html), [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) and [here](http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-sqlite-database-example)

**To get Current date**

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

**To set a reminder**
    you can use the alaram manager to set the reminder the solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520403/how-to-set-alarm-in-android)

***EDIT 2***

```
private class myReminderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while(true)
        for(String s : list){
            Date d = //Make date from the string obtained from SQL
            d.toString().equals(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));

            //Create an alaram or notification
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        Cursor c = null;
        c = db.rawQuery("select startDate,endDate from tablename" , null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 0)
            {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("FirstDate")));
                        list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LastDate")));
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                db.closeDatabase();
            }
            cursor.close();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

}
```

Do the entire thing on [AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) ([example here also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) )so that the main UI thread is not blocked, on pre execute code the database fetching and on do in background use the while loop so that it never ends

This is what i can give rest you do the work... and that's all, rest you have to search and work out your way don't expect me to make and give an entire project

Comment: thank you,i Completed to insert stratDate and fromDate in the table. but i am not able get the date and check with current date and show one reminder message when the app is open

Comment: Retrieve data from database http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/how-to-retrieve-data-from-a-sqlite-database-in-android/ and then store it in string and `currentDateTimeString .equals(date_retrieved_from_database)` and if its true show the reminder

Comment: thank you,can you give me any code demo for fetching dates in store in string array then compare it with current date

Comment: here are some tuts you can refere too 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791892/how-to-retrieve-data-from-database-in-android-creating-database-on-sqlitebrowser

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/226781-how-to-retrieve-data-from-database-to-listview/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Awu7Rlsez_k

http://droideplace.blogspot.in/2009/09/store-and-retrieve-data-in-sql-database.html

Comment: exactly in app I need to set reminder which show message or notification when the current date is match with range of start date to end date. i confusing how to get dates and its range and how to compare with current date and set notification....please send complete solution

Comment: Thank you Very much Girish Nair.

Comment: your welcome, Accept this as solution if you solved it so that this question is closed

Comment: notification is work,but for get the startdate - enddate range and compare current date.

Comment: thanks for help but i have a problem in the given code. The date is defined like Date d="" here i put the query which defines the error that its not convert into the date.Make sure that i am using a sqlquery for finding the range from start date to end date.

Comment: `SELECT StartDate From Dates_Table` will return something like this 28-June-12
`String start_date="28-June-12";`
`formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");`
`Date d = (Date)formatter.parse(start_date);`

Comment: In apps i have to set alarm based on the start date and end date which are stored in SQLITE database.so, how to get both date and compare that dates to Current date and set alarm notification which can work like that apps is load or launch and current date is match with database stored date(means between start date to end date) it show alarm notification or play audio.
Please if have any demo for this or code send me.

Comment: Check these projects

http://code.google.com/p/bells-android/source/browse/#hg
http://code.google.com/p/plus-minus-alarm/source/browse/#git%2Fc2Client_ics_git

Comment: thank you, if i enter start date and end date on edit text based on that can i insert all the date which is between the strar date and end date.send me query or code for that.

Comment: `for (LocalDate date = startDate; date.isBefore(endDate); date = date.plusDays(1))
{
  //Do your code
}`

Comment: thank you girish u guide me alot and providing some of best best tutorial.

Comment: Your welcome and happy diwali :)